# why scala doesn't have a built-in PartialFunctionN?

Tags: scala

scala have a built-in `FunctionN` traits up to [`Function22`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/Function22.scala). it would seem natural to have a corresponding `PartialFunctionN`. so why is it that scala doesn't have it? is there an inherent reason why it wasn't included in scala?

it's easy enough to implement something close to `PartialFunctionN` by myself. we can of course define the obvious:

```
type PartialFunction2[-T1,-T2,+R] = PartialFunction[Tuple2[T1,T2],R]
```

but the returned type would actually be:

```
scala>  val f: PartialFunction2[Int,Int,Int] = {case (2,3) => 8; case (3,2) => 9}
f: PartialFunction2[Int,Int,Int] = <function1>

scala> f(2,3)
res0: Int = 8

scala> f(2,7)
scala.MatchError: (2,7) (of class scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp) ...
```

which is confusing, since it looks like a `<function2>` and not a `<function1>`.

another approach would be to define `PartialFunctionN` recursively:

```
type PartialFunction2[-T1,-T2,+R] = PartialFunction[T1,PartialFunction[T2,R]]
```

but the useage won't be as nice and clean like the previous example, and we still get `<function1>`:

```
scala> val g: PartialFunction2[String,String,String] =  {
case "x" => {case "y" => "male"; case "x" => "female"}
}
g: PartialFunction2[String,String,String] = <function1>

scala> g("x")("y")
res0: String = male

scala> g("x")("x")
res1: String = female

scala> g("y")("x")
scala.MatchError: y (of class java.lang.String) ...
```

so, basically, i'm intrested to know if there's a good reason as to why scala don't have `PartialFunctionN` built in, and as a bonus, i would also like to know if there's a way to mimic the expected functionality, and get a `<functionN>` instead of `<function1>` as the returned type.

Comment: I think that when you call f(2,3) you're really calling f((2, 3)). Maybe you could go with currying...

Comment: of course it f((2,3)). much like any other function with one argument. an `f: Function1[Int,Int]` could be called either `f(1)` or `f 1`. so you are right, of course! :)

Comment: Yeah, and I've noticed you have tried a sort of currying through recursive typing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and get a `<functionN>` instead of `<function1>` as the returned type

In

```
f: PartialFunction2[Int,Int,Int] = <function1>
```

the type *is* `PartialFunction2[Int,Int,Int]`, just as you want. `<function1>` is the result of calling `toString` to show the function in the REPL. Note that given your definition `PartialFunction2[Int,Int,Int]` is a `PartialFunction` and therefore a `Function1`, not a `Function2`. You could define

```
trait PartialFunction2[-T1,-T2,+R] extends Function2[T1,T2,R] {
  def isDefinedAt(x: T1, y: T2): Boolean
}
```

but you wouldn't get any nice syntax (you could add an implicit converstion from `PartialFunction[Tuple2[T1,T2],R]` to `PartialFunction2[T1,T2,R]` though).

> i'm intrested to know if there's a good reason as to why scala don't have `PartialFunctionN` built in

If you had `PartialFunction2` in the standard library, and it was created by your desired syntax, then you'd have to have some different syntax for `PartialFunction` of a tuple. It's complicated enough already.

Comment: I don't think the syntax is the problem. I would expect the compiler to choose the more explicit form. much like it's already doing. for example: `object Foo {def f(t: Tuple2[Int,Int]): Unit = println(s"got a TUPLE of ${t._1} and ${t._2}!"); def f(i: Int,j: Int): Unit = println(s"got 2 regular ints: $i and $j.")}` and try: `Foo.f(2,3)`. you'll get: `got 2 regular ints: 2 and 3.`, and of course, if someone defines both a `PartialFunctionN` and a `PartialFunction[TupleN,R]`, then, upon an invokation of `pf(x,y,...)` it should choose the `PartialFunctionN` implementation.

Comment: I was not talking about overloading, but about definition syntax. If you wrote `val f = {case (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y}` (which is illegal currently but would make sense with this change), should this define `PartialFunction2[Int, Int, Int]` or `PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int]`?

Comment: this is syntactic sugar. if it's really ambiguous (which mean the compiler can't infer the expected type by itself), then I guess the compilation should fail. and you would have to write the more explicit form: `PartialFunction[Tuple2[Int,Int],Int]{case (1,2) => 3}` or `PartialFunction2[Int,Int,Int]{case (1,2) => 3}`

Comment: your answer is good (so +1), but i'm not convinced the syntax is what's preventing this.

Comment: I am not saying this is the only reason, of course. Just _a_ reason.